# ./configure configure: error: does not exist or it is not an exectuable file

Tags: 14.04

Ok so I’m pretty much new to UBUNTU, I had to install it to use `osm2pgsql` for a project and so far I just followed instructions from their wiki up until now. I ran the following command, and it didn't work:

```
./autogen.sh
```

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
```

No "Error" so far so all right,

```
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
```

seemed strange since gettext and gettext-base are both installed
but sure, then I use ./configure and this pops up :

```
configure: error:  does not exist or it is not an executable file
```

So here I am, I tried Googling this error but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: That seems to be an error from the `configure` script itself, however I just pulled from the git repo and can't replicate it. Do you really need to build this from source? There appears to be a fairly recent version in the Universe repository.

Comment: Like I said, I'm pretty new to all this and only following instructions from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql. They specifically say to do this procedure from source.

Comment: You could add the result of `grep '_CONFIG' config.log` but at this point I'm only guessing what the specific error might be. TBH the Q&A format of this site doesn't really encourage this kind of troubleshooting: my advice would be try the repo version, and if that doesn't work for you and you really want to build from source, start a thread over on ubuntuforums.

Comment: You where right, I tried following the instructions on their wiki but getting it from the Universe repository worked just fine. Thank you !